# Loading external AJAX with CORS that include images with relative paths

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

I am loading with AJAX and JQuery content from other website (I use CORS headers so I do not have any cross domain issue).

The loaded HTML content has some images with relative paths so those images are not loaded into the page that makes the AJAX call.

I would like to avoid writting absolute paths in the original content. I know that I could parse the AJAX response with JQuery and add the required base URL so the path to the image becomes absolute but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it

Comment: If you have little local content, you could use the `<base href`

Comment: But that wil affect the whole page not just the loaded content won't it?

Comment: Yes, it is not a good solution if you have more stuff affected. Unless you use an iframe ;)